# "The file in the editor is not runnnable" -intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I can't run this program.I tried  editing the run configuration,marked src folder directory as resource root,again test resource root, but still it won't work.. although building is possible.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZgML.png

Comment: 1. It should be "Sources root" 2. (Java basics) You are expected to have a `public static void main(String[] args)` **directly** inside a `public class`, not from a nested class.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use class Test() in class EncapsulationExample{}

```
public class EncapsulationExample {
    private String name;
    private int x;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public int getValue(){
        return x;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setValue(int x){
        this.x = x;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EncapsulationExample e1 = new EncapsulationExample();
        e1.setName("Aara");
        e1.setValue(10);
        System.out.println(e1.getName()+e1.getValue());
    }
}
```